# How to load a method on startup in webservice

Tags: java, web-services

I have a java webservice using AXIS2 and running on tomcat server.

I need to load a file when the server starts and I do not know how to do it. I have tried adding a main method but it just won't work. Is there any specific stuff that I need to do to load a file when the server starts?

Answer (score 1):

If there's no specific way to do it in the AXIS2 server you could try using a [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Traditional_simple_way) or a [static initialization block](http://isagoksu.com/2009/development/java/understanding-static-blocks/).

Answer (score 0):

Don't know much about Axis, but could you either deploy a ContextListener, or a servlet with `<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>` declared in the web.xml alongside your web service?